# Fraction of two series (help)

Tags: power-series

I've ran across the following expression:

$$ \dfrac{a_1 x + 2a_2 x^2 + 3a_3 x^3 +\  ...}{1 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \ ...}  $$

Now one is supposed to be able to write this fraction of series as:

$$a_1 x + 2 \left( a_2 - 1/2 a^2_1 \right)x^2 + 3 \left( a_3 - a_1 a_2 + 1/3 a^3_1 \right) x^3 + \ ...$$

Any hints on how to do this ?

Comment: Hint: try writing the result as a power series with unknown coefficients, say $b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + \cdots$. Then multiply up and compare coefficients of powers of $x$.

Comment: oh yeah... , I'll do that

Comment: Long division, perhaps? (If you don’t need too many terms…)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* that the problem is
$$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^p n\,a_n\ x^n  }{1+\sum_{n=1}^pa_n\,x^n }$$ rewrite it as
$$\frac{f(x)}x=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^p n\,a_n\ x^{n-1}  }{1+\sum_{n=1}^pa_n\,x^n }$$ Integrate
$$\int \frac{f(x)}x\,dx=\log\Bigg(1+\sum_{n=1}^p a_n\,x^n \Bigg)$$ Now, use
$$\log(1+t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \, \frac {t^k} k$$ Make $$t=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n\,x^n$$ and use the binomial expansion.

When done, differentiate and multiply by $x$ to have the series expansion of $f(x)$.